# ldap schema in development should it match production?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I been using LDAP for many years now and most of the firms I worked for used a development LDAP schema that was identical to the production and QA (staging) schemas. An example suffix would be:

`"dc=firm,dc=com"`

I just started working at a new firm a few months ago and the systems administrator is telling me that I am doing it wrong. He says that in development the suffix should be `"dc=firm,dc=dev"`.

I feel that this is going to cause a lot of issues down the road with programming and moving data for testing, among other things. I would like to get some views on this. I see the situation thusly: **The data should always look like production data even in the development and staging environments.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a matter of preference, however there are upsides to having a development environment named different from production. The most notable being that any scripts run on the development environment will not be likely to be able to do damage if accidentally run on the production environment.

In Fantasy Life<sup>TM</sup> we would have completely segmented networks that weren't even physically connected. One for production, one for development and testing. They would have different passwords and user accounts that would signify if it was a testing environment or not.

In Real Life<sup>TM</sup> that's not the case. However, a "defense in depth" of your production data can utilize the simple touch of not using the exact same LDAP name between the two.

Does that make things messy if you want to take a development change and migrate it to production? Perhaps a *tiny* bit, however if there's not enough automation or standardization in an environment to be able to simply and effectively change `suffix "dc=firm,dc=com"` to `suffix "dc=firm,dc=dev"` then I think there are larger problems.

### TL;DR

Both approaches are fine, if there's a larger context of security involved. I wouldn't go so far as to say one is wrong and the other correct. Take the new approach in stride and learn from it.